# SFML my move function is not working correctly

Tags: c++, sfml

In my SFML application, my own move function does not work properly. If I write the code directly to the main function, it works correctly.

My aim is moving and rotating a car according to the coordinates and given road tiles.

The road is:

[image]

And each road tiles are 239*239 and car starts at 150*150.

My move function is:

```
void Vehicle::move(int increment, int increment2, float &ax, float &ay, sf::Sprite &mySprite)
{
    ax += increment;
    ay += increment2;

    if(ax == 150 && ay == 150)
    {
        mySprite.setRotation(0);
        increment = 1;
        increment2 = 0;
    }

    else if((ax == 239*2 + 90) && ay == 150)
    {
        mySprite.setRotation(90);
        increment = 0;
        increment2 = 1;
    }

    else if((ax == 239*2 + 90) && ay == 239*2 + 150)
    {
        mySprite.setRotation(0);
        increment = 1;
        increment2 = 0;
    }

    else if((ax == 239*4 + 90) && ay == 239*2 + 150)
    {
        mySprite.setRotation(90);
        increment = 0;
        increment2 = 1;
    }

    else if((ax == 239*4 + 90) && ay == 239*4 + 90)
    {
        mySprite.setRotation(180);
        increment = -1;
        increment2 = 0;
    }

    else if((ax == 150) && ay == 239*4 + 90)
    {
        mySprite.setRotation(270);
        increment = 0;
        increment2 = -1;
    }

}
```

My main function is:

```
float x = 150.f;
float y = 150.f;
float angle = 0.f;
int increment = 1;
int increment2 = 0;

sf::RenderWindow renderWindow(sf::VideoMode(1200, 1200), "Traffic Simulator");

tVehicleType myVehicleType = VEHICLE5;

sf::Sprite mySprite;
sf::Texture myTexture;

Vehicle *myVehicle;

myVehicle = new Vehicle(myVehicleType, x, y, angle, mySprite, myTexture);


sf::FloatRect boundingBox = mySprite.getGlobalBounds();
mySprite.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(boundingBox.width / 2, boundingBox.height / 2));

while (renderWindow.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;

    while(renderWindow.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
             renderWindow.close();
    }

    mySprite.setPosition(x, y);

    renderWindow.clear(sf::Color::White);

    renderWindow.draw(mySprite);
    renderWindow.display();

    myVehicle->move(increment, increment2, x, y, mySprite);
```

If I write the code like this, this code does not work and I have to write like this. 
If I write the move function to the last line of the main code directly, it works fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I forgot to add renderWindow part. It was added by: sf::RenderWindow renderWindow(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Traffic Simulator");

Comment: You can click the edit button above to update your code.

Comment: It's not clear that what do you want, and what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@CodingLab, my aim is this and if I add the code to my main function, this happens :

[image]

However, if I write the code to the function, this happens:

[image]

The car does not go below, it only goes in the +x direction.